# How to create user account in grails using netbeans?

Tags: grails, netbeans

I have problem in creating user account in grails using netbeans. Show me the coding of how to create the new user account in grails using the netbeans IDE.

Comment: Install the spring security plugin and follow the docs

Comment: There are many resources and examples on the web. http://tinyurl.com/454vccq

Answer (score 3):

Don't expect this to be quick and easy. You have to create User class yourself before creating new Users, and set it up to work as a User.

- Start with learning some security plugin - [spring-security](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html), I suggest.
- If you need to manage users, start with [creating required domain classes](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html) and [spring-security-ui](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/index.html).

And this has nothing to do with Netbeans or whatever IDE, it's just the code you create with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this screencast-series, which explains everything. It is done with SpringSource Toolsuite, but you can do it in whatever editor you use (e.g. Netbeans)

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

Greetings,

Jan